# Export Microsoft CRM contacts including e-mail marketing data

Tags: excel, dynamics-crm-2011

I have been requested to export all contacts out of the CRM, and I am not too familiar with the tool or excel even. There is a variable for each contact named E-mail: allow or do not allow. I need a column for this in a CSV spreadsheet.

Any guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Click on advanced find.

2) Select Contact under "Look For".
3) Click "Edit Columns" and add all the fields you require to export (including the E-Mail field).

4) Click "Results"

5) Click Export Contacts

6) Select "Static worksheet with records from all pages in current view"\

7) Click Export

NOTE: There is a 10,000 record limit for export to excel. If you are On-Prem this can be increased by changing the setting in the database,  follow the [steps here](http://mscrmtech.com/crm2011-extending-the-10000-record-limit-when-exporting-to-excel/).

Comment: Note that there is a 10000 record limit for export to excel. If you are On-Prem this can be increased by changing the setting in the database http://mscrmtech.com/crm2011-extending-the-10000-record-limit-when-exporting-to-excel/

Comment: This is great! Although it only gave me 250 rows, I should have tens of thousands. Please advise a solution. Note that the CRM is not on premise, but cloud hosted.

Comment: I noticed that there are only 250 results per page in CRM, although I am trying to export all CRM contacts.

Comment: Did you select "Static worksheet with records from all pages in current view" ? This will give you all the records in the current view up to 10000 records. Anything past that you will need to use an SSIS connector to pull the data from CRM.  I have used Kingsway Soft's SSIS connector with a lot of success in the past.

Comment: @SunilAlbuquerque I have edited your post to show the note telling about the limitation and how to bypass it.